# juju ssh fails because of permission denied (public key)

Tags: juju

when I try doing a juju ssh into one of the machines, it returns an error

```
2012-12-06 14:16:16,695 INFO Connecting to environment...
2012-12-06 14:16:25,671 INFO Connected to environment.
2012-12-06 14:16:26,994 INFO Connecting to unit sqldb/0 at ec2-54-251-4-139.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Permission denied (publickey).
```

I can still ssh into nodes I created a while back (2 months ago). I'm not sure what's happening. It seems juju is not copying over my public key to the new nodes I'm adding for some reason. Is it some sort of configuration issue?

Comment: Juju, by default, uses your `id_rsa.pub` for the public key it copies. Do you still have a copy of this on your machine for your user in `.ssh`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I do have this. 
On explicitly setting authorized key path to id_rsa.pub in the config file - it's working again. It was not picking the public id by default though.

Not sure why that was happening.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to add your ssh key to the mode. You can do that using [`juju add-ssh-key`](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/commands#add-ssh-key).

The following command adds your public ssh key from the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file. If that file doesn't exist, you need to generate an ssh keypair.

```
juju add-ssh-key "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"
```

You can also specify the public key manually:

```
juju add-ssh-key "ssh-rsa qYfS5LieM79HIOr535ret6xy
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQA6fgBAAABAQCygc6Rc9XgHdhQqTJ
Wsoj+I3xGrOtk21xYtKijnhkGqItAHmrE5+VH6PY1rVIUXhpTg
pSkJsHLmhE29OhIpt6yr8vQSOChqYfS5LieM79HIOJEgJEzIqC
52rCYXLvr/BVkd6yr4IoM1vpb/n6u9o8v1a0VUGfc/J6tQAcPR
ExzjZUVsfjj8HdLtcFq4JLYC41miiJtHw4b3qYu7qm3vh4eCiK
1LqLncXnBCJfjj0pADXaL5OQ9dmD3aCbi8KFyOEs3UumPosgmh
VCAfjjHObWHwNQ/ZU2KrX1/lv/+lBChx2tJliqQpyYMiA3nrtS
jfqQgZfjVF5vz8LESQbGc6+vLcXZ9KQpuYDt joe@ubuntu"
```

After adding the key, you'll be able to ssh to any machine.